# How to access to a property defined in messages.properties file?

Tags: grails, groovy, properties, internationalization, multilingual

I have a Groovy Grails application and I want to access programmatically to a property defined in messages.properties.

As a test, I've tried the following statement:

```
println "capacity.created: ${messages.properties['capacity.created']}"
```

But it doesn't work (throws an exception).

Any help is welcomed.

Luis

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a way to access to message properties directly wothout re-reading all the 
messages properties files (message_de.properties, message_fr.properties, etc.)
It is is very easy.

```
message(code:"capacity.created")
```

and it works!

Luis

Comment: I have a separate class it's not a controller , I tried this and it's not working...any suggestion ?

Comment: @CPU100 inject `messageSource` into that class and use the `getMessage` method.

Comment: This worked for me where I had to pass a dynamic value for the Title: <g:layoutTitle default="${message(code:'message.index.title')}"/>

Answer (score 70):

For reading property files in Groovy you can use the utility class [ConfigSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ConfigSlurper) and access the contained properties using GPath expressions. However, you have to be aware that `ConfigSlurper` doesn't support standard Java property files. Normally the `ConfigSlurper` will be used to read .groovy files that may be similar to a property file, but adhere to standard groovy notation, thus Strings are inside quotes and comments start with `//` or are inside a `/* */` block. So, to read a Java properties file you need to create a `java.util.Properties` object and use that to create a `ConfigSlurper`:

```
def props = new Properties()
new File("message.properties").withInputStream { 
  stream -> props.load(stream) 
}
// accessing the property from Properties object using Groovy's map notation
println "capacity.created=" + props["capacity.created"]

def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(props)
// accessing the property from ConfigSlurper object using GPath expression
println "capacity.created=" + config.capacity.created
```

If you only use the property file from within Groovy code you should use the Groovy notation variant directly.

```
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File("message.groovy").toURL())
```

This also gives you some nice advantages over standard property files, e.g. instead of

```
capacity.created="x"
capacity.modified="y"
```

you can write

```
capacity {
  created="x"
  modified="y"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What you did is valid for any property file but message is an i18n file. I d'ont think that this is going to work if the locale of the client is set to other language. I mean, you are not reading message_de, message_es, message_fr, etc. Besides that all the messages are already read by the system. I wouldn't read them again if I can avoid that.

Comment: Just a notice for loading from classpath use `properties.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("message.properties"))`

Comment: In newer java Versions ```toURL()``` is deprecated, simply do the following:
```def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File("message.groovy").toURI().toURL())```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a best practice to read `message.properties` for i18n. You can use:

```
message(code:"capacity.created")
```

in controllers as @Luixv suggested or

```
messageSource.getMessage("capacity.created",
                        [].toArray(), "Capacity Created.", null)
```

in any other spring/grails bean after injecting the bean `messageSource`.