# How to read messages from message.properties in config.groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, internationalization, grails-2.0

I dont want to hardcode the 'training.defaultStartTime' value in config.groovy Instead I have to read it from message.properties, The result will be like this

In **message.properties**

```
dev.training.defaultStartTime = 09:00
prod.training.defaultStartTime = 10:00
```

In **config.groovy**

```
  environments {
        development {
            training.defaultStartTime = message of  code 'dev.training.defaultStartTime' in message.properties 

        }
        production {
            training.defaultStartTime = message of code 'prod.training.defaultStartTime' in message.properties 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why hardcode it in message.properties rather than config.groovy?

Comment: For the internationalization purpose, I want to use message.properties.I have many default values which are different for different countries

Comment: But those will be loaded on application startup, and will not relate to the location of the user viewing the site...

Comment: @Vinay: Have you find solution of the issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [groovy: How to access to properties file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055959/groovy-how-to-access-to-properties-file)

Answer (score 2):

Just want to read it? If you want to display it in a gsp, use `<g:message code="dev.training.defaultStartTime"/>`, (you can find some useful stuff about it [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/message.html)).

If you're in a controller and want to use it there, go with:

```
message(code: 'dev.training.defaultStartTime')
```