# Logback - read properties from file with groovy configuration

Tags: properties, groovy, logback

In logback with xml configuration I can read variables/properties from file with:

```
<property file="src/main/java/chapters/configuration/variables1.properties" />
```

How can I do the same with groovy configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConfigSlurper` in groovy is used to read properties. It is easier to read a `groovy` config file (even with DSL notations). In order to read `.properties` file there has to be a work around. Converting the properties to `java.util.Properties` and then parsing it with `ConfigSlurper`.

Synonymous to this [SO Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055959/groovy-how-to-access-to-properties-file).