# Replace the string in file using groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, groovyshell

I have got a file with name "silent.txt". This file is having a line as follows

```
bop4InstallDir = myProps.cordys_install_dir + "/" + instanceName
```

I want to replace the above text with

```
bop4InstallDir = "/abc/xyz/pqr"
```

Using groovy script how do I accomplish this?
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code worked:

```
def file = new File("silent.txt")
def fileText = file.replaceAll("bop4InstallDir\\ \\=\\ myProps.cordys_install_dir\\ \\+\\ \"\\/\"\\ \\+\\ instanceName", "bop4InstallDir\\ \\=\\ \"/opt/cordys/bop4/defaultInst1\"")
    file.write(fileText);
```

Answer (score 3):

Not very elegant, but this should work.

```
def file = new File("silent.txt")

file.text = file.text.replace('bop4InstallDir = myProps.cordys_install_dir + "/" + instanceName', 
'bop4InstallDir = "/abc/xyz/pqr"')
```

Comment: Its not working. The error is like "expecting EOF, found ')' @ line 6, column 34.
   'bop4InstallDir = "/abc/xyz/pqr"')"

Comment: i think you have misplaced the quotes. Please copy the code as is from the above and then try.

Comment: The copied code did not work. I has some thing to do with special characters like '/', '+'...

Answer (score 0):

Is silent.txt well formatted property file? In this case you can use a various ways to access them, much more secure, than dumb replace.

Look [groovy: How to access to properties file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055959/groovy-how-to-access-to-properties-file)
or [ConfigSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ConfigSlurper)

Comment: Its not a property file. Its a groovy script.