# In Groovy how to replace a string in a file?

Tags: groovy

I'm following the answer given in [Replace the string in file using groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670269/replace-the-string-in-file-using-groovy), but am getting an error. I just want to replace, for example

```
From
version=1.1.0

To
version=1.1.1
```

in some file. I do

```
String sv1 = '1.1.0'
String sv2 = '1.1.1'
def file = new File(`/some_path/someFile')
def fileText = file.replaceAll("version=$sv1", "version=$sv2")
file.write(fileText)
```

I get

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.io.File.replaceAll() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl, org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [version=1.1.0, version=1.1.1]
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.io.File.replaceAll() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl, org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [version=1.1.0, version=1.1.1]
    at pre-push.updatePatchVersion(pre-push:154)
    at pre-push.compareVersions(pre-push:188)
    at pre-push.run(pre-push:219)
```

Are the dots (.) in the string messing it up? What's the proper syntax if so? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `replaceAll()` on the file's contents, not on the `File` instance itself.

```
def fileText = file.text.replaceAll("version=$sv1", "version=$sv2")
```

Comment: The answer in the link I referred to is wrong then. This is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This will do your entire task in one line

```
new File(`/some_path/someFile').text=new File(`/some_path/someFile').getText().replaceAll("version=1.1.0", "version=1.1.1")
```